# Actionscript MovieClip hitTesting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, hittest

So I am making a side scrolling platform game and I have a number of enemies on my stage. I have made separated classes for my each unique type of enemy. My issue is, in order to do scrolling, I have my player movie clip stay at the centre and have everything else move. I pushed my enemies into arrays by enemy type, I could loop through the arrays and move the enemies one by one. However that would be too much calculations to do on the computer, so I tried putting all my enemies inside one collective enemies movieclip so I can move the single movieclip. My issue is, when i have them out by themselves, they can do the hittest against my platform just fine, when I put them into a movieclip they are not able to detect the platforms. Can anyone tell me why is that so? Any help is greatly appreciated. If anyone need to see my codes please ask.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure moving enemies one by one would be too heavy processing? Did you check it? I have no problem moving my enemies, the game only uses 1% CPU.

Comment: And about your question, I think the problem is in local enemy coordinates relative to the container, but I'd like to see your hittest code.

Comment: are you using the built in hittest method? the part of the code where you hittest would help

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko For my computer there isn't much problem. It's because my lecturer told me about performance optimizing, limiting the amount of calculations to as little as possible so i thought i'd give it shot.

Comment: @MartonPallagi Regarding the codes, i will upload my files somewhere because I'm not exactly sure whether any other codes will affect anything, but it might take a while

Comment: @Alketrax You see, you need to check hittest for each enemy so you need a loop anyway. You can move them in that loop. Most of the processing time is spent on drawing, not moving. What lecturer told you is right but there is such thing as micro optimization, it's when you do optimizations in a way that will not gain any noticeable performance.

Comment: @Alketrax You don't need to upload the whole code jsut the part where you hittest the two movieclips. I was just curious if you were using the built in `hitTest` method which uses bounding boxes.